# Ubuntu freezes constantly when propietary Nvidia drivers are installed

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, freeze

I'm having an issue when I'm running the proprietary nvidia drivers for my ASUS laptop running ubuntu 14.04.   The display freezes periodically (about once every few minutes).  I know the system is still running though because I can hear my music still playing, and closing and opening the lid unfreezes the display.

Additionally the problem goes away when I switch to the open source video drivers.

Anyone have a similar experience or know of a solution?

Edit:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 12dd

Kernel driver in use: i915

04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 745M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 12dd
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: When I added the 'Net -A2' part I got 'egrep: Net: No such file or directory'.  So I ran it without that part and updated my question with that result.  I'm not sure if that will give the same result though.

Comment: do you actually use nvidia propriatary driver indeed or it's nouveau you mean?

Comment: Oh I was using nouveau when I ran that command, should I switch back and run the command?

Comment: I mada a typo. It is `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D'  -A2`. The problem looks like your driver is not installed correctly.

Comment: I re-ran the command with my command with my nvidia drivers, and updated my question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

These freezes happened to me too. It looks like the Nvidia driver from Ubuntu repository does not handle relatively new adapters well.

But also it can be overheat. This also should be considered. I would start with upgrading the driver and kernel this way.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

reboot

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

reboot.

Comment: Running these commands has caused my pc to become unbootable

Comment: @RyanStull What you mean "unbootable"? GUI does not start? You can remove this driver from console.

Comment: Sorry, I switched back to the old kernel and its working once again

Comment: You can remove 3.19 kernel image and headers, if they cause problems.